# MongoDB complex Aggregate function

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I'm facing a problem with the aggregate function done on the MongoDB schema model. I have a `Medicine` model that has the following form.

[image]

and an `Order` model that has the following form.

[image]

What I want to do is filter `totalsales` by medicine name so for example if I have panadol, catafast, etc.

I want to know how much Panadol I have sold and so on.

I'm trying to use an aggregate function to group all completed orders and filter them then trying to lookup for the medicine name by the `id` in the array. However, I got an empty array and I'm pretty sure of my data. What I'm not sure about is the pipeline in the function.

```js
const getSalesDataByMedicine = async (req, res) => {

    try {
        const medicineSales = await Orders.aggregate([
            {
                $match: {
                    status: "Completed"
                }
            },
            {
                $unwind: "$items"
            },
            {
                $group: {
                    _id: "$items.MedicineId",
                    totalQuantity: { $sum: "$items.Quantity" },
                    totalAmount: { $sum: { $multiply: ["$items.Quantity", "$amount"] } }
                }
            },
            {
                $lookup: {
                    from: "medicine", // Replace with the actual name of your Medicine model's collection
                    localField: "_id",
                    foreignField: "MedicineId", // Assuming Medicine _id is used in MedicineId field
                    as: "medicineData"
                }
            },
            {
                $unwind: "$medicineData"
            },
            {
                $project: {
                    _id: 0,
                    medicineId: "$_id",
                    medicineName: "$medicineData.name", // Adjust to your actual field name in Medicine model
                    totalQuantity: 1,
                    totalAmount: 1
                }
            }
        ]);

        return res.status(200).json(medicineSales);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error("Error fetching medicine sales data:", err);
        return res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal Server Error" });
    }


};
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like `$items.MedicineId` is a string, try converting that to ObjectId

Comment: This could be the case but do you have a suggestion for the implementation? or how may I make this conversion I tried to ask the chatbot but it wasn't helpful. I ended up adding a lot of code in the pipeline and it didn't work.

Comment: You could convert it to ObjectId in the `$group` stage. `_id: { $toObjectId: "$items.MedicineId" }`.

Comment: I wonder whether using Medicine collection to join Order collection is better performance-wise than using Order collection to join Medicine collection. As I can see the `$unwind` stages aren' needed when you make the query with Medicine collection to join Order collection.

Comment: I tried the objectId thing and still nothing, how is that different if I swapped the join order ?

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your current query, you need to make these changes:

1. Convert `items.MedicineId` to `ObjectId` in the `$group` stage.
2. The foreign field is `_id`, the `_id` field from the document in the *medicine* collection but not the `MedicineId`.

```
[
  ...,
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        $toObjectId: "$items.MedicineId"
      },
      ...
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "medicine",
      // Replace with the actual name of your Medicine model's collection
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      // Assuming Medicine _id is used in MedicineId field
      as: "medicineData"
    }
  },
  ...
]
```

---

Notice that your calculation for the total sales amount of each product is incorrect as you are multiplying by the `amount` in the *order*. It is supposed to be multiplied by the unit price of the medicine. (*medicine* document -> `price`)

```
totalAmount: { $sum: { $multiply: ["$items.Quantity", "$amount"] } }
```

So your query should be:

```
db.order.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      status: "Completed"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$items"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        $toObjectId: "$items.MedicineId"
      },
      totalQuantity: {
        $sum: "$items.Quantity"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "medicine",
      // Replace with the actual name of your Medicine model's collection
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      // Assuming Medicine _id is used in MedicineId field
      as: "medicineData"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$medicineData"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      medicineId: "$_id",
      medicineName: "$medicineData.name",
      // Adjust to your actual field name in Medicine model
      totalQuantity: 1,
      totalAmount: {
        $multiply: [
          "$totalQuantity",
          "$medicineData.price"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo Solution 1 @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/PGT9gvNgN9G)

Also as mentioned in the comment, I think that joining the *medicine* collection (base) with the *order* collection may perform better by eliminating those `$uwind` stages which are costly in queries.

```
db.medicine.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "order",
      let: {
        medicineId: {
          $toString: "$_id"
        }
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$status",
                    "Completed"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $in: [
                    "$$medicineId",
                    "$items.MedicineId"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $set: {
            items: {
              $filter: {
                input: "$items",
                cond: {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$this.MedicineId",
                    "$$medicineId"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "orders"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      orders: {
        $ne: []
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      medicineId: "$_id",
      medicineName: "$name",
      // Adjust to your actual field name in Medicine model
      totalQuantity: {
        $sum: {
          $reduce: {
            input: "$orders",
            initialValue: [],
            in: {
              $concatArrays: [
                "$$value",
                "$$this.items.Quantity"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      totalAmount: {
        $multiply: [
          {
            $sum: {
              $reduce: {
                input: "$orders",
                initialValue: [],
                in: {
                  $concatArrays: [
                    "$$value",
                    "$$this.items.Quantity"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "$price"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

The usage of `$reduce` is to flatten the nested arrays for `items`, which is an array field in each document in the `orders` array.

[Demo Solution 2 @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/siH44Imdql5)